# Support WCF soap based clients inside web API with .NET Core

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, wcf, soap

I have WCF application which I am trying to migrate to Web API with .NET core.
Once I am done with migration I can ask clients to upgrade their apps to start using new REST endpoints and not to use WCF service.
My only concern is that not all clients can migrate to new service at same time and I have to keep supporting both WCF and REST client until all clients migrated to use REST service.
I also can not have old services running as it adds infrastructure cost. Is there any way to support WCF clients in the same REST app ? If the client don't migrate can they still address the service using old endpoint and old soap payload.

Comment: Generally speaking in framework there is no such support of WCF services. but there are some third party nuget packages like CoreWCF via which you can achieve it. Do bit google and you can find it. i rememeber i were able to port some of my wcf services to .net core

Comment: It depends on whether your WCF service uses webhttpbinding. If it is not webhttpbinding, this operation cannot be performed. For example, we use basichttpbinding, when the client communicates with the server, the client will have a channel, but there is no similar channel in webapi.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hosted service in .net core. In order to achieve that, you can add manually the ip:port/wcfinterface from the connected services (wcf web service reference provider) this is an additional tool, .net core is still supporting client side, you the way to call it is a little bit different. I have been using async methods with wcf and they work pretty fast.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: Hi Jorge, I am not looking for wcf client solution in .net core.. I am looking to migrate wcf service into .net core.

Comment: You can't do that because .net core isn't supported, the normal way is to create a wcf service by regular.net. if I were you,  I'll just go by API Rest, gRPC, or something else.